# Servlet Filter is not being hit intermittently

Tags: java, angular, servlets, servlet-filters

I am facing a very strange issue.

Issue is we have a web application (war)which is built using angular 4 and it also has a "Servlet filter" which scans each and every request for a token and if that token is not available servlet filter will navigate to third party login page. 
If token is available , it simply loads index.html and other data.
Token and some other params will be available as session cookies to current web app.

I have accessed the app URL and logs in to app and performs some actions in app and closes the browser window without logging out and I tried to open the same URL again , Servlet filter is not getting called.

If I refresh the browser window, filter is getting called.

If I clear the browser cache Servlet filter is getting called . I have observed same behavior in chrome and firefox.
I did check localhost access log, I don't see my request there.
Can anyone have any ideas on what is the issue and how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Do you mean your site is restored exactly to the last session i.e. logged-in if you re-open the browser window/tab without logging out ?

Comment: Yes Just 1)login 2)close the window 3) re-open the window 4)Enter Url or click a bookmark

Comment: @aravind Can you attach your filter' code?

Comment: Hi @S.Denis code is very complex it is more than 1000 lines with lot of methods and if else statements.I cannot post everything here. Do u want me to look at a particular piece of code ?

Comment: Can you post your filter mapping and filter code. Just to understand if all calls are being checked for the token. Also, when reopening have you checked if the token is sent in the request ?

Comment: Request is not all coming to filter..i mean doFilter method..If there is a problem in mapping refresh of a window will not hit the filter..but it is hitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is Google Chrome is caching so request is not all going to server. But when I refresh chrome is sending the request to Server. When I disable cache , everything is working fine. A good lesson about caching.